# How can I run a while loop inside a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

I'm new to Python3.
The code below is just for easy illustration of this question. I'm wondering is there anyway I can run a while loop inside a for loop. It seems whenever the while loop return false it will end everything.

```
x = 0
for i in range (2):
    while x < 2:
        print ('I')
        x +=1
```

The outcome I want is to iterate the while loop twice so that it should print 'I' 4 times.

Thank you

Comment: You never set x back to zero, so it will execute the print statement only twice and won't do anything in the second iteration of the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
for i in range (2):
    x = 0  
    while x < 2:
        print ('I')
        x +=1
```

You need to reset `x` right before the `while` loop because otherwise, `x` will stay equal to `2` after the first iteration of the `for` loop and the `while` loop will exit instantly because `2 < 2 == False`.

Answer (score 1):

To do this, we can use the same `range` function that we used for `i`.

```
for i in range(2):
    for x in range(2):
        print('I')
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also reset `x` at the beginning of the loop:

```
for i in range(2):
    x = 0
    while x < 2:
        print('I')
        x += 1
```